# Mono.Cecil and Unity not playing nice together

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono.cecil

I'm trying to use Mono.Cecil to patch my custom user scripts in Unity.

I have code I want to inject into my custom user scripts in Unity to avoid writing the same lines of code in every MonoBehaviour in the project.
However, when I do:

```cs
using (AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assembly.Location, new ReaderParameters() { ReadWrite = true }))
{
    //Do some patching here
    assemblyDefinition.Write();
}
```

Then I get an exception saying

> IOException: Win32 IO returned 1224

Which apparently means that the file is locked from being written to.

If I instead try to use:

```cs
File.Delete(sourceAssemblyPath);
File.Move(targetAssemblyPath, sourceAssemblyPath);
```

Then the dll gets patched correctly, but when I try to play the application then the scripts in my scene lose reference, as if the replacement of the file causes them to think the scripts on the scene objects no longer exist in the project (Which I guess would make sense since I DID delete the dll they were in to replace it with the new one).

Has anyone any idea on how to patch the user's project assembly in Unity while maintaining usability of the current project?
Or should I resort to only patching during build or something?
Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: When is this code running? If you do it using [InitializeOnLoad] then the assemblies have obviously already been loaded so modifying them at that point isn't going to help; you'd need to load assemblies once to trigger Cecil than reload again to load the modifications every time you would normally reload only once. Try using UnityEditor.AssemblyReloadEvents.beforeAssemblyReload. Last time I tried something with Cecil I was able to use a single `var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);` to both read and write the file without a delete/copy.

Comment: Currently I'm running it manually via a menu command.
These are interesting suggestions though, I'll give them a try soon and report back, thanks~

Comment: So I'm doing this now:

using (Stream assemblyStream = new FileStream(assembly.Location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyStream, new ReaderParameters() { ReadWrite = true }))
                        {
                            assemblyDefinition.Write(assemblyStream);
                        }
                    }

And still get the 1224 IO exception.

Comment: Same if I try even just this:

using (FileStream assemblyStream = new FileStream(assembly.Location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[assemblyStream.Length];
                        assemblyStream.Write(bytes, (int)assemblyStream.Position, (int)assemblyStream.Length);
                    }

Comment: You need to set `assemblyStream.Position = 0;` between the read and write so you're actually overwriting from the start of the file. Not sure if that's the cause of the error. Other than that it looks pretty much the same as my code (though I wasn't using any ReaderParameters).

Comment: Apparently the 1224 error code means the file is in use, which usually means you're trying to open a second stream while the previous is still open or something. That doesn't appear to be the case in the code you just posted, but that means it's a regular IO problem rather than Cecil specifically.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what's changed since the last time I tried it, but using 

                                    assemblyDefinition.Write(assemblyStream);
Seems to work now, so you might want to convert this comment to an answer so I can accept it :)

One question though:
I did use beforeAssemblyReload as you suggested, however the only place I found fitting to register to that event was DidReloadScripts or InitializeOnLoad, but that means that the method I registered won't be called until the next time beforeAssemblyReload is triggered.
Where did you register to the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I tried something with Cecil I was able to use a single `var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);` to both read and write the file without a delete/copy.

If you do it using `[InitializeOnLoad]` then the assemblies have obviously already been loaded so modifying them at that point isn't going to help; you'd need to load assemblies once to trigger Cecil than reload again to load the modifications every time you would normally reload only once. You'll want to use `UnityEditor.AssemblyReloadEvents.beforeAssemblyReload` instead.

`beforeAssemblyReload` gets called after the new assemblies are recompiled but before they are loaded. So you'd use `[InitializeOnLoad]` to register a callback (`[DidReloadScripts]` seems identical in every case I've tried) which should ensure that all newly compiled assemblies get processed going forward. In some cases this might not happen (such as if scripts need to be compiled when you first open the editor so it hasn't registered your event yet) so you'll probably also need to run your processing code immediately on initialisation as well and force an assembly reload if anything it changed using `UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.RequestScriptReload();` or `UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.Refresh();`.

The best way I've found to mark an assembly as processed is to inject an attribute definition and add an instance of it to the assembly, then check for it by name and skip the assembly if it exists. Without a way to do this, you'd be processing every assembly in the project every time scripts recompile rather than only processing ones that have been modified.

---

Edit: to process the assemblies of a build, try this:

```
    private static bool _HasProcessed;

    [PostProcessScene]
    private static void OnPostProcessScene()
    {
        if (_HasProcessed || !BuildPipeline.isBuildingPlayer)
            return;

        ProcessAssemblies(@"Library\PlayerDataCache");
        _HasProcessed = true;
    }

    [PostProcessBuild]
    private static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget target, string pathToBuiltProject)
    {
        _HasProcessed = false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you had any success in using this method for builds?
The patched assemblies aren't used when building because new assemblies are being built instead.
But OnPostprocessBuild and OnPreprocessBuild don't seem to be relevant for this, nor does using BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer right after injecting the code.
I can't seem to find a way to use the injected code in a build.

Comment: It's been a while since I played with it and I never seriously implemented anything so I can't remember, but I added the code I was using to my answer.